External HDD slowdown due to internal cache issue?
Running an rsync backup from Win10 internal 8T disk onto external 2.5inch 4T disk via USB3. Expected copy volume >2T. After about 500G the Win10 taskmanager performance tab shows the receiving disk 'activity' near 100% though transfer rate is oscillating at low speeds between KB and low single digit MB values. The source disk is at low percentage activity and does not seem to cause the bottle neck.
I could think this is a cache ram issue in the external disk. Anybody has corroborating info? Or is it a thermal issue? The external disk feels hand warm, not hot.
I'm not looking for a repair. Just trying to understand the root cause.
Should mention that for the first 2hrs of copy the write speed was pretty stable between 50MB and 100MB.

